# using def cannot search element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm just trying to do simple program but I'm stuck and right now I'm so frustrated.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
myList = []

def addnew():
    name = []

    name.append(input("Enter name: "))
    myList.append(name)

    print(myList)

def find():
    global myList
    src = input("Enter name: ")
    if src in myList:
        print("Yes, name exist")
    elif src not in myList:
        print("Name not exist")

def view():
    print(tabulate(myList, tablefmt='psql'))

while True:
    print("[1] to add")
    print("[2] to search")
    print("[3] to view")
    inp = input(">> ")
    if inp == '1':
        addnew()
    elif inp == '2':
        find()
    elif inp == '3':
        view()
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

My `def find():` not working as I expected. :(

```
def find():
    global myList
    src = input("Enter name: ")
    if src in myList:
        print("Yes, name exist")
    elif src not in myList:
        print("Name not exist")
```

From what I have found, if the list like this `['bob']` result is good but when the list like this `[['bob']]` the result name not exist.

> If I remove `name = []` and change `myList.append(input())` the tabulate result is so messy :)

Result:

```
Enter name: bob
['bob']   
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 3
+---+---+---+
| b | o | b |
+---+---+---+
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>>
```

Comment: `myList = [['bob']]` is a list of lists, it's a different thing. You'd need to write `['bob'] in myList` to find it...

Comment: I don't think you need the `name` list, just `myList.append(input("Enter name: "))`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I already change to ```myList = ['bob']``` but the tabulate result not quite nice to see.

Comment: You can format the table later, to look nice; it's more important that the program works correctly, not that it's pretty.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez hihihi. ok ok noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter new name, just add the string to `myList`. Then, when you use `tabulate()`, create one column data from this `myList`:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
myList = []

def addnew():
    myList.append(input("Enter name: "))    # <-- just append new string to myList
    print(myList)

def find():
    global myList
    src = input("Enter name: ")
    if src in myList:
        print("Yes, name exist")
    elif src not in myList:
        print("Name not exist")

def view():
    print(tabulate([[v] for v in myList], tablefmt='psql'))   # <-- create one column data from myList
    # or you can use:
    # print(tabulate({'name': myList}, tablefmt='psql'))

while True:
    print("[1] to add")
    print("[2] to search")
    print("[3] to view")
    inp = input(">> ")
    if inp == '1':
        addnew()
    elif inp == '2':
        find()
    elif inp == '3':
        view()
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

Prints (for example):

```
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 1
Enter name: Andrej
['Andrej']
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 1
Enter name: John
['Andrej', 'John']
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 1
Enter name: Mary
['Andrej', 'John', 'Mary']
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 3
+--------+
| Andrej |
| John   |
| Mary   |
+--------+
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
>> 2
Enter name: John
Yes, name exist
[1] to add
[2] to search
[3] to view
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = []
name.append(input("Enter name: "))
```

This code makes `name` a list. When you input "bob", `name` would be like `['bob']`. Then you apppend `name` to `myList`, so that `myList` would be a list of list like `[['bob']]`. You can't find a `'bob'` in a `[['bob']]`.

So you don't have to make `name` a list. Just replace the two lines with:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
```